# Evaluating a random elisp function in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

So, I've been having fun with [this web site that creates random themes for Emacs](http://sweyla.com/themes/). I've been saving the resultant .el files and loading them when starting Emacs. Each color theme can be started by evaluating an elisp expression prefixed with `inspiration-`.

Unfortunately, I don't know elisp. Can someone help me figure out how I might write a function that looks at what "inspiration-" prefixed functions are available, and randomly evaluate one of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to build up a solution to these problems incrementally. If you just want to try my answer, skip to the `defun` block of code at the end. I go to the `*scratch*` buffer, in `lisp-interaction-mode` to try these code snippets out. You can type `C-j` after an expression and Emacs will run it and insert the results in the buffer.

The `apropos` function searches for symbols matching some pattern, including regular expressions. So we can find all symbols starting with "inspiration-" like so:

```
(apropos "^inspiration-\*" t)
```

But that result has a list for each symbol with some other information. We can discard that and just take the symbol name, which comes first, using the `first` function:

```
(mapcar #'first (apropos "^inspiration-\*" t))
```

Some of those aren't functions, so let's remove any that fail the `functionp` test:

```
(let ((symbols (mapcar #'first (apropos "^inspiration-\*" t))))
  (remove-if-not #'functionp symbols))
```

Now let's randomly choose one of those. I'm switching from `let` to `let*` because `let*` allows me to reference earlier definitions in the same initialization, e.g. using `symbols` when defining `functions`.

```
(let* ((symbols (mapcar #'first (apropos "^inspiration-\*" t)))
       (functions (remove-if-not #'functionp symbols))
       (number (random (length functions))))
  (nth number functions))
```

Now let's turn that into a new lisp function (and let's not have the name start with `inspiration-`). I'll mark it as `interactive` so that you can run it via `M-x use-random-inspiration` in addition to using it in other elisp code. The other big change is to use `funcall` to actually run the randomly selected function:

```
(defun use-random-inspiration ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((symbols (mapcar #'first (apropos "^inspiration-\*" t)))
         (functions (remove-if-not #'functionp symbols))
         (number (random (length functions))))
    (funcall (nth number functions))))
```

So add that to your `$HOME/.emacs` file and try it out.

**EDIT: Avoid the Apropos buffer popup**

```
(defun use-random-inspiration ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((pop-up-windows nil)
         (symbols (mapcar #'first (apropos "^inspiration-\*" t)))
         (functions (remove-if-not #'functionp symbols))
         (number (random (length functions))))
    (funcall (nth number functions)))
  (kill-buffer (get-buffer "*Apropos*")))
```

Comment: Harold -- thank you. That is exactly what I needed. I found "mapatoms" and started trying to build something with this but not knowing elisp it was a slow road to pave. This is much more straightforward.

Comment: Turns out the only issue I have is that the apropos function brings up a new window of its own in the *Apropos* buffer. I don't see a way to suppress it, but can you?

Comment: Took me a while to figure out that apropos window pop-up. I've added a fix for that marked as an EDIT. Turns out it is a 2 part fix. First, we need to set the pop-up-windows variable to nil so that the screen doesn't split in half. That makes the pop-up take over the window. Then we can kill the *Apropos* buffer right away to go back to the buffer we were in.

Answer (score 4):

I was working on an answer to this when Harold beat me to the punch.  But, his answer got me thinking.  I hadn't known about the Inspiration theme generator before and I really like the idea!  So, while this isn't what you asked for, it still may be interesting to folks reading this question.  It selects a random theme from the Inspiration site, downloads it into a buffer, evaluates it, and executes the resulting function after deleting the buffer.

Basically, it's random color themes on tap. I haven't figured out the random numbering scheme yet for light and dark, but if I do, this could easily be turned into a `random-dark` and `random-light` pair of functions.  Which you could then trigger based on downloaded sunrise and sunset times for your lat and lon... =)

```
(defun random-inspiration ()
  "Downloads a random Inspiration theme and evaluates it."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((num (number-to-string (random 1000000)))
         (buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously
                  (concat "http://inspiration.sweyla.com/code/emacs/inspiration"
                          num
                          ".el"))))
    (save-excursion
      (set-buffer buffer)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward "^$" nil 'move)
      (eval-region (point) (point-max))
      (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
      (funcall (intern-soft (concat "inspiration-" num))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but after finding the inspiration theme generator, I really wanted a nice way to tweak them...

So I made this... http://jasonm23.github.com/